# Excel Macro to Combine two excel spreadsheets based on duplicate data

Tags: vba, excel

I have two excel spreadsheets which contain data. Both of these sheets contain an ID number and then other corresponding data. Sheet 1 is essentially a master sheet which contains all existing ID numbers (and other corresponding data), while sheet two is a specific set of data that will only contain some of the ID numbers found in sheet 1 (All ID numbers in sheet 2 exist in sheet 1, but not the other way around). Currently, sheet 1 contains data from columns A to F, with the ID number in column C, while sheet 2 contains data from columns A to C with the ID number on column A. Also note that ID numbers are in increasing order as we move down the sheet and each ID number in it's respective sheet is unique.

What I want, is if an ID from sheet 2 is equal to an ID in sheet 1, then I would like to tack on columns B and C from sheet 2, to the end of the corresponding row in sheet 1, and then also delete any rows in sheet 1 where there does not exist the same ID number in sheet 2. To clarify, sheet 1 looks like this:

```
+-------+----------+--------+--------------+
|Year   |Country   |  ID #: |Columns D,E,F |
+-------+----------+--------+--------------+
|2012   |CA        |123456  |data          |
+-------+----------+--------+--------------+
|2015   |US        |565382  |data          |
+-------+----------+--------+--------------+
|2008   |US        |765382  |data          |
+-------+----------+--------+--------------+
|2012   |CA        |956471  |data          |
+-------+----------+--------+--------------+
```

Sheet 2 looks like this:

```
+-------+----------+--------+
|ID #:  |Quantity  |Value   |
+-------+----------+--------+ 
|123456 |435       |12523   |
+-------+----------+--------+
|765382 |1136      |52342   |
+-------+----------+--------+
|956471 |49        |5562    |
+-------+----------+--------+
```

Then after combining the rows with the same ID number and deleting all the ones from sheet 1 that do not contain a corresponding ID from sheet 2, we get:

```
+-------+----------+--------+--------------+-----------+---------+
|Year   |Country   |  ID #: |Columns D,E,F |Quantity   |Value    |          
+-------+----------+--------+--------------+-----------+---------+
|2012   |CA        |123456  |data          |435        |12523    |          
+-------+----------+--------+--------------+-----------+---------+
|2008   |US        |765382  |data          |1136       |52342    |                  
+-------+----------+--------+--------------+-----------+---------+
|2012   |CA        |956471  |data          |49         |5562     |          
+-------+----------+--------+--------------+-----------+---------+
```

Since my sheet contains hundreds of thousands of rows, I cannot do this manually, so I need a macro that can finish this task much more efficiently.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub mergeSheets()

Dim c As Range, cfind As Range, x, dest As Range, cfind1 As Range
On Error Resume Next
Worksheets("sheet3").Cells.Clear
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
.UsedRange.Copy Worksheets("sheet3").Range("a1")

For Each c In Range(.Range("a2"), .Range("c2").End(xlDown))
x = c.Value

    With Worksheets("sheet2")
    Set cfind = .Cells.Find(what:=x, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If cfind Is Nothing Then GoTo line1
    .Range(cfind.Offset(0, 1), cfind.End(xlToRight)).Copy
        With Worksheets("sheet3")
        Set cfind1 = .Cells.Find(what:=x, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If cfind1 Is Nothing Then GoTo line1
       cfind1.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial
        End With 'sheet3
     End With  'sheet2
line1:
 Next
 End With 'Sheet 1
    Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a "code for me" site, but rather "help me with my code". Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to ask a question. Please post any code/macros/formulas you've tried so far.

Comment: Why VBA?  Why not simply use `VLOOKUP` on sheet1, and then filter out the `#N/A`'s?

Comment: So where did you go?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a different approach than your code, loop through column C in sheet1  and find the ID# in columnA in sheet2, then get the info, copy and paste would not be required.

```
Sub Get_It()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim LstRw As Long, Rng As Range, c As Range, Fx As Range

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")

    With sh

        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = .Range("C2:C" & LstRw)

        For Each c In Rng.Cells

            Set Fx = ws.Columns(1).Find(what:=c, lookat:=xlWhole)

            If Not Fx Is Nothing Then
                c.Offset(, 4) = Fx.Offset(, 1)
                c.Offset(, 5) = Fx.Offset(, 2)

            Else: MsgBox c & " is Not Found"' remove msgbox if desired, just an example

            End If

        Next c

    End With

End Sub
```